# How to enable button in view based on checkbox value in partial view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using JQuery (or knockout) how can I enable the submit button in the view based on whether a checkbox is checked in the partial view?

I have a razor view called `CreateUser.cshtml` and it contains a partial view called _`createUserDetails.cshtml` which contains html textboxes and checkboxes. The partial view is inside an `@html.beginform` block in the CreateUser view and this view also contains the submit button. How can I update the submit button based on the values in the partial view?

Comment: How do you want to update your submit button to ? You want to do that on page load ? Please provide expected output clearly to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what you mean by update submit button, but you could use jQuery selectors to check the state of the checkboxes, then do something with the submit button based on that.

Something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if($('#checkbox1').prop("checked") == true){
      $('#submitButton').prop("disabled", true);       
   }       

   //To get the values in the textboxes you could do

   var value = $('#textbox1').val();

   //which will give you whatever the user has entered in the textbox       
});
```